# windows 7, python 3.7 (anaconda), mayavi, vtk: Failing to import mlab

Tags: python, windows, vtk, mayavi.mlab

for my thesis, i tried to get mayavi under python 3.7 (Anaconda 3) up and running for the last three days. With no success at all.

When typing:

`from mayavi import mlab`

python shows me:

```
----> from vtkIOExodusPython import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: ... modul not found
```

A quick research shows me, that the modules from vtk are loaded via all.py and that all files live in peaceful harmony in the same directory ../Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/vtkmodules/.

In all.py, a series of imports are triggered. In this case all.py ->.vtkIOExodusPython.py -> vtkIOExodusPython.pyd.

vtkIOExodusPython.pyd is the first file in the list (line 70) that triggers this error. But i can't find any difference to any of the files before that are going to be loaded just fine.

If i comment the the line, the next error occurs on .vtkIOMINC, then vtkIONetCDF and vtkIOParallel. After writing a "#" in front of those lines, from mayavi import mlab shows no problems anymore.

A PATH-Variable has been added in Windows. Also a PYTHONPATH-Variable to this folder. No improvement at all.

How am i going to get everything working? What am i doing wrong?

Hope you can give me some advise.

Schmidt